# Comparing values in multiple text files and database

Tags: java, php, mysql

I have multiple text files and an a database table. The database contains a  fixed number of entries and the text files have more entries.

For Example:

------------text1.txt-----------

44-CAT-IV-CORE  626518 T19P45

44-CAT-IV-OUTER 626522 LB0N08

44-CAT-IV-EXTER 626956 AG8N15

44-CAT-IV-DOUT  626965 PQ7715

------------text2.txt-----------

44-CAT-IV-CORE  626518 T19P50

44-CAT-IV-OUTER 626522 LB0N08

44-CAT-IV-EXTER 626956 AG8N15

44-CAT-IV-DOUT  626965 PQ2718

Many files like this....

The database looks like:

|unit|   |value|     |name-part|       |version|

|CAT-IV|  |626518|  |CAT IV CORE|      |T19P43|

|CAT-IV|  |626522|  |CAT IV OUTER|     |LB0N08|

|CAT-IV|  |626956|  |CAT IV EXTER|     |AG8N15|

I want to get those part names and values from the text files whose value or version or both **do not match on the database**(only for those parts where the name exist in the database, like here we need to ignore CAT-IV-DOUT as it is not on the database)

I tried loading the database values to a text file and then comparing against text files, however it seems inefficient. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you the read the information from the files and them compare to those on the database? I assume your database is MYSQL or the likes and has highly optimized search algorithms. You want to run this operations using SQL as it has better algorithms than what you could come up with.

Comment: I tried pushing the MYSQL database values to a text file and then getting the two difference between two text files using:  grep -v -f textfile1.txt textfile2.txt > textout.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. put all lines of the files in an array (file();)
2. go trough the databasetable and compare each arrayelement with the current data from the database.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, I am not very sure of doing that . Could you please help me with some code